# Storing HTML into a javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, kohana

I'm having some trouble with some javascript.  I'm using jQuery to dynamiclly add rows
to a table.  Additionally the javascript is being generated from some PHP and Kohana code.

Here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function delExtensionNumber(element){
        $(element).prev().attr('value', 'X'); 
        $(element).parent().parent().hide();
    }

    function addExtensionNumber(){
        lines = <?php echo form::dropdown($ext_id."[did]", $lines, ''); ?>;
        extensions = <?php echo form::dropdown($ext_id."[extension]", $phones, ''); ?>;

        $('#line-extensions > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+lines+'</td><td>'+extensions+'</td><td><input type="hidden" name="'+<?php echo $ext_id;?>+'[state]" value="0" /><a class="hide" onclick="delExtensionNumber(this)"></a></td></tr>');

        <?php $ext_id++; ?>
    }
</script>
```

This works fine in Firefox.  But in IE and Chrome it doesn't work.  Nothing happens in google Chrome.  In IE I get an error on the page.  The error is a syntax error.  It doesn't like the < character after the word line.

Ok, so I thought I better put some quotes around this string.  But... when I do that nothing works.

Comment: Could you show what is outputted in the firefox version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just going to assume that `form::dropdown` is spitting out plain HTML. In Firefox, this is being interpreted with [E4X](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x), and then turned back into a string when concatenated. IE and Chrome do not support E4X. To make it work, you could do something like this:

```
lines = <?php echo json_encode(form::dropdown(...)); ?>;
```

**Edit:** The reason it's not working when you're putting quotes around it is because the HTML contains quotes. The code above will escape the quotes correctly.

Comment: You are correct, `form::dropdown()` does return a string of HTML.

Comment: Frantastic.  Not what I would have thought of but that worked great! thanks alot.

Comment: Actually I was pretty careful with the quotes but i still couldn't make it work.  So the json encode version did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not support XML literal syntax, you can't write e.g. `line = <div>foo</div>`, you have to enclose the data into a string.

```
lines = '<?php echo form::dropdown($ext_id."[did]", $lines, ""); ?>;'
```

could work (and you should possibly also escape `'`)

Comment: That's what I thought might work, but actually it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score -2):

I **strongly** recommend you to use Jquery DOM Creation Plugin

- [**Easy DOM creation for jQuery**](http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype)

it would be a lot, easier.

Comment: I don't see why. The HTML is generated by Kohana, and so I don't see why it would be necessary to imitate that function client-side. For all I know, it might rely on something from the database, and would be impossible to implement client-side.

Comment: i misunderstood your question.