# Storing HTML in a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript

I am currently coding a website that will allow a user to input data into a MySQL database using a WYSIWYG editor.  The data stores into the database without a problem and I can query it using PHP and display it on my webpage.

Up to this point everything is working ok until I try to move the HTML stored in the MySQL database into a javascript variable.  I was able to get it working using CDATA[], but not for every browser.  It works in Firefox, but not IE or Chrome.  I am looking for a solution that will be able to work in all of the browsers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you post the code you've used to store HTML in JavaScript?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a HTML escaping issue. Could use more info/code though to clear this up.

Comment: Looks like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176744/storing-html-into-a-javascript-variable

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PHP:

```
<script>
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($htmlFromDatabase); ?>
</script>
```

The json_encode method, while normally used for encoding JSON objects, is also useful for converting other PHP variables (like strings) to their JavaScript equivalents.

Comment: To clarify, calling json_encode on a php string will output the correct code for a JS string, that is, wrap it with quotes and escape  characters in the strings.

Comment: won't you need to wrap the result from json_encode with quotes on the outside? e.g. var foo = "<?php etc %>";

Answer (score 0):

"Safefy" your code, like this

```
str_replace( array("\r", "\r\n", "\n", "\t"), '', str_replace('"','\"',$str));
```

The above function clears linebreaks, and tabs so that your code appears in one line. If it breaks into more than one line, then it cannot be parsed as a string in JS and an error is thrown. Also we are escaping " to \",  maybe there are more string replacements that need to take place, it depends in your content.

and inline it in javascript,

```
//<![CDATA[ 
    var myHtml = <?php echo '"'.$stuff.'"'; ?>;
//]]>
```

keep in mind the '"' part so that it appears like this var myHtml = "test";